# Styling command in onTop side menu

Tags: codenameone

What we do in commnads in older side menu is that we put the "uiid" in putClientProperty() method but it doesn't work in ontop side menu. How to style it?

```
Command services = new Command("  Services", servicesIcon) {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    }
};
f.getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(services);
services.putClientProperty("uiid", "commandProp");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It still works but because the side menu is constructed eagerly instead of lazily you don't see this.

Instead of this:

```
f.getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(services);
services.putClientProperty("uiid", "commandProp");
```

Do:

```
services.putClientProperty("uiid", "commandProp");
f.getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(services);
```